# How to get auth status from Shopify theme

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

Currently, I am working on a shopify store where I want to trigger some action if the user is customer is logged in to the store and places an order. The problem is, Shopify store allows deferred login and in the checkout page, when unlogged user puts email/phonenumber; shopify store automatically creates a user profile based on the given username/password. The customer is still not logged in to the store but his order json is showing the customer id the store created, and I am not able to find anything on how to check the auth status of the customer at the time of placing the order?

In our theme, we are checking the user by liquid object 'customer', but this object is showing the created customer id when we try to access it after placing the order. Is there a way to get user auth status from shopify?